# NodeJS embedded database (persistent & encryptable)?

Tags: database, node.js, encryption

Is there a decent database for nodejs that is able to be embeded & encrypted so that if someone does get that file of data, a password also has to be known ?

I am coming up short & though things like nosql, nedb, etc. exists, none of them see to be able to handle encryption of said data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- sqlcipher can be built for [mapbox/sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3#building-for-sqlcipher)
- Also, using encryption with nedb is really easy, you just create a crypto cipher and perform the operation in and out. See this [example from bitcrypt](https://github.com/coolaj86/bitcrypt/blob/master/lib/bitcrypt.js#L27)

You'd basically do the same thing as `cipherHelper` and `decipherHelper`, but you'd put them in the `afterSerialization` and `beforeDeserialization` callbacks.